# Searching MySQL database by a Regex match (in reverse)

Tags: mysql, regex

If I have a database table that has one column that contains a regex pattern, is it possible to return rows (without systematically testing each row in turn) that a string matches?

for example, a table like this:

```
RowID     RegExPattern
1         foo\.$
2         bar\.$
3         baz\.$
4         (foo|bar)\.$
```

and an input string like this:

```
foo.php
```

will return `RowID`s `1` and `4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I have a database table that has one column that contains a regex pattern, is it possible to return rows [...] that a string matches?

Yes, that's possible.

```
SELECT RowID
FROM yourtable
WHERE 'foo.php' REGEXP RegExPattern
```

Note though that your regular expressions won't match. If you omit the `$` then they will.

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91f663/1)

> (without systematically testing each row in turn)

Err... no. You need to test each row.

Comment: but its all done on the server? I meant as in, you don't have to download each row in turn and test the expression with an input